# Modifying Android Search for ListView

Tags: android, search, searchview

I'm new to android app development and currently trying to figure out how to add search to an app. I did some searching and the tutorial that was the simplest for me to understand is [here](https://www.beginnersheap.com/android-searchview-tutorial-android-search-bar-example/).

The app runs and searches as it should. The only issue is that the tutorial is for searching a ListView. The activity that my app's search is hosted in has other details(itemview, textview) that need to be on the screen so a ListView won't work for what I'm trying to do. How do I modify this example to provide a dropdown of suggestions as the user types into the search box? Ideally, I would like a search as seen in this [image here](https://androidhub.intel.com/library/nglauber/AndroidSearch_1.png).

ItemSearch.java

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_search_activity);

        final String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December"};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, months);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                String text = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

}
```

item_search_acitivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_view_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.me.ItemSearch">


    <ImageView
        />

    <ImageView
        />

    <ImageView
       />

    <TextView
        />

    <TextView
         />

    <TextView
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

menu_search.xml under res/menu/menu_search

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="@string/hint_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

searchable.xml under res/xml/searchable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW">
</searchable>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml I've added

```
<activity android:name=".ItemSearch" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you already tried https://androidhub.intel.com/en/posts/nglauber/Android_Search.html

Comment: @zombie yes, I have. Any suggestions on how to merge the two without the CitySuggestionProvider.java class? I would just like the app to search the months String array above.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of dropdown suggestion functionality you would use `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Example usage below:

In your layout file:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/auto_complete_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/key"/>
```

In a resource file such as `arrays.xml` or `strings.xml`:

```
<string-array name="suggestions">
    <item>January</item>
    <item>February</item>
    <item>March</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

In your fragment or activity:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTv;

...

AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTv = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_tv);
autoCompleteTv.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(view.getContext(), R.array.suggestions, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line));
```